# Fermi's Golden Rule; what frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, feynman-diagrams, fermis-golden-rule

Fermi's Golden Rule is given by:
$$  \newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon} \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>} \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|} \newcommand{\braoket}[3]{\left<#1\right|#2\left|#3\right>}
 \Gamma=\f{2\pi}{\hbar} |\braoket{f}{V}{i}|^2\f{dN}{dE}$$
my question is what frame do we need to calculate these quantities? I am particularly looking at (simple) Feynman diagrams where:
$$\braoket{f}{V}{i}=\f{1}{\tilde q^2-\mu^2}$$
This is clearly Lorenz invariant but what about $dN/dE$. Does it matter what frame we calculated it in? What about the decay cross section $\sigma$ or differential cross sections $d\sigma/d\Omega$ does it matter what frame this is  calculated in?

Comment: What's wrong with the rest frame of *i* ? A decay rate and lifetime are then transformed to any moving frame; are you unfamiliar with the lifetime of ultrarelativistic muons?

Comment: Ah so if I find $\Gamma$ in a particular frame it will correspond to $1/\tau$ in that frame?

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_(particle_physics)).

Comment: [And](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation_of_moving_particles).

Comment: When it comes to [phase space](http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~libby/Teaching/Lecture4.pdf) you can transform accordingly.

Comment: @CosmasZachos If you put this into an answer I will accept it